# How Do You Change Telescope To Port 80?

Tags: meteor, telescope

I just setup Telescope and I was wondering how I can change the default port to 80 instead of 3000? Telescope also uses the javascript framework Meteor so I am not sure if this might be related to Meteor, but just wanted to add that as well.

Thanks for the help! This probably is a very easy fix, but just wanted to ask!

[Link to Telescope main project](http://www.telescopeapp.org)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--port` option when running the Meteor command. So `meteor --port 80`.

Comment: Thanks @Sacha! Is there a way of running the meteor service as a daemon so I could run meteor in the background as a process and free up my terminal? Something like 'meteor --port 80 -d' maybe?

Comment: @user1896756 If you are using OsX you can open multiple terminal windows or tabs, exactly like a browser. During development I usually run meteor, meteor mongo and a terminal for git operations.

Comment: @user1896756 if you are on linux you can do this `meteor &` . adding the `&` makes it run in the background.